# Add errors to the Partial View before rendering

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have some code that renders **Partial View** based on some model to html.

And after this I send this html to the page.

In case of the errors I would like to use

```
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

in order to display them.

So my question is following: **Is it posible to add some errors to model right before the rendering?**

```
#region Regenerate Partial View in case of error
var moduleLocation = new ModuleLocation(); // Some custom class

string renderedPartialView = RenderPartialViewToString("_CreateLocationModalPartial", moduleLocation);
#endregion



#region Method to render Partial View
public string RenderPartialViewToString(string viewName, object model)
{
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
                viewName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

            ViewData.Model = model;

            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
                ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
                viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

                return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            }
}
#endregion
```

Comment: have you tried with ViewData.ModelState.AddModelError("", "error") ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is, by adding the errors to the `ModelState`:

`ViewData.ModelState.AddModelError("key", "error")`